# Gridding scattered data without interpolation

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, vectorization

I have three vectors, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, which represent 3d coordinates of some data found in matrix `V` (i.e. `V = f(X,Y,Z)`). Below are some features of this data (assumptions / asserts, if you will):

- `X` and `Y` are of the same length, which is (usually) different than `Z`'s.

  ```
  numel(X) == numel(Y);
  ```
- The amount of unique elements in `X` is generally different from the amount of uniques in `Y`.
- All values in `Z` are unique.

  ```
  numel(unique(Z)) == numel(Z);
  ```
- `V` has the size `[numel(X), numel(Z)]`.

In the past, I did not differentiate between `X` and `Y`, and I referred to them using a single index, which made it easy to plot charts that have "XY combination number" (i.e. `1:numel(X)`) on one axis and `Z` on the other, so that the size of `V` worked out nicely.

Presently, I would like to see the effects of `X` and `Y` separately, which is why I want to visualize this in 3d, using a mixture of [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) and [`contourslice`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourslice.html).

The scatter part is easy enough, since I can `repmat` `X` and `Y` along their singleton dimension `numel(Z)` times, and similarly for `Z` (using `numel(X)`). This results in:

[image: Result of the scatter]

As for the contours, these require data to be provided as 3d arrays - which means I have to place the points in a structured grid. Creating the grid coordinates `XX`, `YY`, `ZZ` is straightforward using `meshgrid`:

```
[ XX, YY, ZZ ] = meshgrid( unique(X), unique(Y), unique(Z) );
```

What I'm struggling with is creating the 3d array `VV`.

From the image above we can see that the majority of the volume does not contain points - and I would very much like to **keep it that way**. In other words, the ideal `VV` should contain only the points which correspond to the original dataset, and the rest of the space should contain `NaN`s.

Functions like [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) and [`interp3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) perform interpolation, which would "fill holes" inside the cloud of points - which is **extremely undesired**. I think indexing can be used here to populate `VV` using values from `V`, but I can't think of a way to do it.

My question is: **how can I generate `VV` that does not contain any interpolated data**?

Here's a minimal example:

```
%% Generate some data:
X = randi(10,100,1);
Y = randi(15,100,1) - 5;
Z = 1:50;
V = X./Y.*Z;

%% Scatter plot:
nXY = numel(X); nZ = numel(Z);
figure();
scatter3( reshape( repmat(X,[1, nZ]),  [], 1), ...
          reshape( repmat(Y,[1, nZ]),  [], 1), ...
          reshape( repmat(Z,[nXY, 1]), [], 1), ...
          [], V(:), '.');

%% Contours:
% Create the 3d grid:
[XX, YY, ZZ] = meshgrid( unique(X), unique(Y), unique(Z) );

% Preallocate VV:
VV = NaN(size(XX));

% Populate VV: <--------------------------------------------- Help needed with this stage
ind = randperm( numel(XX), numel(V) ); % PLACEHOLDER 
VV(ind) = V;

% Plot:
hold on; contourslice(XX, YY, ZZ, VV, X(2), Y(3), Z(10) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a possibly-overkill way by matching up all your gridded indices to all your linear data points. For this we need to inject a few dimensions in order to compare the 3d arrays `XX` etc to the 2d arrays `X` etc elementwise:

```
Xbc = reshape(X, [1,1,1,size(X)]);
Ybc = reshape(Y, [1,1,1,size(Y)]);
Zbc = reshape(Z, [1,1,1,size(Z)]);
```

These arrays are reshaped such that they broadcast with the arrays `XX` etc of size `[N,M,K]` ("bc" stands for broadcasting). So elementwise comparison works now:

```
match = reshape((XX == Xbc) & (YY == Ybc) & (ZZ == Zbc), [size(XX), numel(V)]);
```

This logical array has size `[N,M,K,P,Q]` if `V` is size `[P,Q]`. It contains exactly as many `true`s as you want:

```
>> sum(match(:)) == numel(V)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

So now we need to pick out the corresponding indices along the first three dimensions and pair them up with the right element of `V`. We need some linear-to-multiindex elbow grease:

```
[ii,jj,kk,ll] = ind2sub(size(match), find(match));
```

Now all the arrays on the left hand side are size `[numel(V), 1]`; the first three give you the indices into `XX` etc, and the last one gives the index into `V`.

```
V_inds = ll;
VV_inds = sub2ind(size(VV), ii, jj, kk);

VV(VV_inds) = V(V_inds);
```

Now, for some reason I only see 3750 unique indices among 5000 in the result:

```
>> numel(VV_inds)           

ans =

        5000

>> numel(unique(VV_inds))

ans =

        3750
```

I can't seem to find any other reason for this than that some of your original data points overlap due to the repetitions in the values of `X` and `Y`, so you can't actually represent them in a 3d grid of unique points (because some 3d points contain more than one data point). I believe the following proves this:

```
>> size(unique([X,Y], 'rows'))

ans =

    75     2

>> size([X,Y])

ans =

   100     2
```

There are 100 `(x,y)` pairs, but only 75 unique ones. No matter how you combine these with orthogonal `z` point sets, you'll end up with repetitions in your points. So you either have to cull the redundancies in your raw data, or you need to find another representation (or taking the mean for clashing values).

---

I think I've got a more efficient version as well, using the indices generated by `unique` during its run. Note that I'll assume that you're using `meshgrid` instead of `ndgrid` to generate the grids, so that the dimensions of the resulting arrays (and also `VV`) correspond to the unique sizes along `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, respectively.

```
% take the indices
[uX, ~, iX] = unique(X);
[uY, ~, iY] = unique(Y);
[uZ, ~, iZ] = unique(Z);

% generate mesh and allocate result
[XX, YY, ZZ] = ndgrid(uX, uY, uZ);
VV = NaN(size(XX));

% switch from `iX`, `iY` and `iZ` to a 2d mesh of size `[P,Q]` where `iX` and `iY` are of size `[P,1]` and `iZ` is of size `[Q,1`]:
% a.k.a. lazy repmat
iXbig = iX + 0*iZ.';
iYbig = iY + 0*iZ.';
iZbig = iZ.' + 0*iX;

% turn 3d indices into linear index into VV
VV_inds = sub2ind(size(VV), iXbig, iYbig, iZbig);

% profit
VV(VV_inds) = V;
```